# Change image with the new one

Tags: php

I want to change my old image with the new one but it didn't change. That always show image in database.

This is my form to update image

```
Gambar Produk Awal : <img src='upload/<?php echo $dataproduk['gambar'];?>'><br>
<input type="hidden" name="gambarproduk" value="<?php echo $dataproduk['gambar']; ?>"/>
Gambar Baru : <input type="file" name="gambarproduk1" id="gambarproduk"/><br>
```

This is my function to update image

```
$nama_file = $_FILES['gambarproduk1']['name'];
if(!empty($nama_file)){
    $new_location = "upload/" . $nama_file;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['gambarproduk']['tmp_name'], $new_location);
} else {
    $nama_file = $_POST['gambarproduk'];
}
```

Anyone please help me...

Comment: Is the file uploading to the servers directory?  How are you getting the variable `$dataproduk['gambar']`?

Comment: Your code seems fine. Recheck your form has attribute encype like <form action="your_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: $dataproduk['gambar'] is image in my database.

Comment: i'm already add enctype but it still not working

Comment: Try to use a echo value in both if and else statement to check which one is executing. and also check whether the file is uploaded. Check the uploading has any error using `vardump($_FILES['gambarproduk']['error'])`.